# Transparent SurfaceView

Tags: java, surfaceview

in my project I have a joystick. Here's what it look like[image]

My problem is that black color, how to make it transparent.

Here's my code

```
public class JoyStickView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnTouchListener{
private float centerX;
private float centerY;
private float baseRadius;
private float hatRadius;
private JoyStickListener joyStickCallback;

    public JoyStickView(Context context){
       super(context);

       getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
       getHolder().addCallback(this);

       setZOrderOnTop(true);

       setOnTouchListener(this);

       if(context instanceof JoyStickListener){
          joyStickCallback = (JoyStickListener)context;
       }
    }

...
}
```

My .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.akoni.control.Controller">

<com.example.akoni.control.JoyStickView
    android:id="@+id/joyStickLeft"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<com.example.akoni.control.JoyStickView
    android:id="@+id/joyStickRight"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/joyStickLeft"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDITED**

Full code for Joystick.

```
public class JoyStickView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnTouchListener{
private float centerX;
private float centerY;
private float baseRadius;
private float hatRadius;
private JoyStickListener joyStickCallback;

public JoyStickView(Context context){
    super(context);

    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setZOrderOnTop(true);
    setOnTouchListener(this);

    if(context instanceof JoyStickListener){
        joyStickCallback = (JoyStickListener)context;
    }
}

public JoyStickView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int style){
    super(context, attributeSet, style);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setOnTouchListener(this);

    if(context instanceof JoyStickListener){
        joyStickCallback = (JoyStickListener)context;
    }
}

public JoyStickView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context, attributeSet);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setOnTouchListener(this);

    if(context instanceof JoyStickListener){
        joyStickCallback = (JoyStickListener)context;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    setupDimensions();
    drawJoyStick(centerX, centerY);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final float displacement;
    final float constrainX;
    final float constrainY;
    final float ratio;
    if(v.equals(this)){
        displacement = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX() - centerX, 2) + Math.pow(event.getY() - centerY, 2));
        if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if(displacement < baseRadius) {
                drawJoyStick(event.getX(), event.getY());
                joyStickCallback.onJoyStickMoved((event.getX() - centerX)/baseRadius, (event.getY() - centerY)/baseRadius, getId());
            }
            else {
                ratio = baseRadius / displacement;
                constrainX = centerX + (event.getX() - centerX) * ratio;
                constrainY = centerY + (event.getY() - centerY) * ratio;

                drawJoyStick(constrainX, constrainY);
                joyStickCallback.onJoyStickMoved((constrainX - centerX)/baseRadius, (constrainY - centerY)/baseRadius, getId());
            }
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            drawJoyStick(centerX, centerY);
            joyStickCallback.onJoyStickMoved(0, 0, getId());
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public void setupDimensions(){
    centerX = getWidth() / 2;
    centerY = getHeight() / 2;
    baseRadius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 3;
    hatRadius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 6;
}

public void drawJoyStick(float newX, float newY){

    if(getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
        Canvas canvas = this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        Paint color = new Paint();

        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        //base Circle
        color.setARGB(100, 50, 50, 50);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, baseRadius, color);

        //top Circle
        color.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawCircle(newX, newY, hatRadius, color);

        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

public interface JoyStickListener{
    void onJoyStickMoved(float xPercent, float yPercent, int source);
}
```

}

The black color is still there. I want to see only the joystick, the circle ones. It is already functional though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Does your joystick image have an alpha channel? If no, edit it with "Gimp", for instance, then add an alpha channed and erase the black area.

Comment: Kindly see the edited, it is my full code for the joystick. Thanks.

Comment: You can't see if an image have an alpha channel or not just by looking at the code. Open it with "Gimp" and check whether it have one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of three lines of code:

```
    setZOrderOnTop(true);
    getHolder().addCallback(this); 
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

and put them in all JoyStickView.
It works for me